# Angular filter observable by map keys

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an observable `categories` that gets a list of all categories from an api with url and name

```
{url: "http://test.com/1", name: "test1"}
{url: "http://test.com/2", name: "test2"}
```

and I have a list of `selectedkeywords` with a name and a category (with url and name). I made a new map because i need to reorder them by category so I have a list of keywords that belong to a category like this:

```
this.keywordsSelected$ = this.keywords$.map((keywords) => {
  return keywords.reduce((acc, keyword) => {
    if (!acc.has(keyword.category.url)) {
      acc.set(keyword.category.url, []);
    }
    acc.get(keyword.category.url).push(keyword);
    return acc;

  }, new Map<string, Keyword[]>());
});
```

So I get a map with an url as key and the keywords in the array:

```
Map(2) {"http://test.com/2" => Array(5)}
```

The first list categories has a specific order I need to retain. Thats why i want to filter that list by the second list so i show only the categories that are in the 'selecetedkeywords' list. Something like this:

```
categories.filter(cat => cat.url === selectedkeyword.key
```

I am a bit new with reactive programming so obviously I am missing something but maybe someone can give me a push in the right direction ?

Comment: Can you be more specific? extend your question a bit more about relation between `categories` and `selectedkeywords` :).

Comment: Can you make a simple example that show what you don't understand? It seems like `combineLatest`, `withLatestFrom` or `forkJoin` could be what you're looking for.

Comment: I have edited my question a bit so I hope it's more clear what i want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with the suggestion from @martin to use combinelatest:

```
 const key$ = this.keywordsSelected$.switchMap(keys => Observable.from(keys));


const testing = Observable.combineLatest(this.categories$, key$)
  .map(([category, keyword]) => {
    return category.filter(cat => (cat as any).url === keyword[0]);
  });'
```